# Spring Integration - messaging gateway to expose overloaded methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have an interface that is exposed by a messaging gateway

**SomeInterface.java`**

```
interface SomeInterface {
    Outcome doSomething(String p1);
    Outcome doSomething(String p1, String p2);
}
```

**rest-beans.xml**

```
<int:gateway id="rest.someRestClient"
             service-interface="SomeInterface">
    <int:method name="doSomething" request-channel="rest.doSomething1"/>
    <int:method name="doSomething" request-channel="rest.doSomething2"/>
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="rest.someRestClient"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway url="${rest.http.url}/v1/doSomething1"
                           request-channel="rest.doSomething1"
                           http-method="POST"
                           message-converters="rest.messageConverter"
                           header-mapper="rest.headerMapper"
                           expected-response-type="Outcome">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway url="${rest.http.url}/v1/doSomething2"
                           request-channel="rest.doSomething2"
                           http-method="POST"
                           message-converters="rest.messageConverter"
                           header-mapper="rest.headerMapper"
                           expected-response-type="Outcome">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to expose both methods defined in the interface as the methods are overloaded.

The above `xml` does not work because of the overloaded methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with XML, use the `@MessagingGateway` annotation instead (and `@Gateway` on the methods to configure the channels), together with `@IntegrationComponentScan` which will find the annotation and generate the gateway in the same way as the XML.